# DataTables button displayed according to row value

Tags: datatables

I have created a JQuery DataTable from mysql row as below
with the help of PHP.
What I want is to display the button of the last Column
depending on a certain value of the $row['Status'] so I am not using JSON Data
in order to use the data object inside the DataTable variable.
Any suggestions?

```
 <td>'.$row['Status'].'</td>
<td><button id="'.$row['ticket_id'].'" onclick="showDetails(this)" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CommentModal">Edit</button></td>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you only want to show the button  with id `id="'.$row['ticket_id'].'"`
 you may just can use a simple if and concatenate echoes the result like this :

```
<td>'.$row['Status'].'</td>
<td>';
<?php
if($row['Status'] == 'active'){
  ?>
    <button id="'.$row['ticket_id'].'" onclick="showDetails(this)" class="btn 


  btn-default" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CommentModal">Edit</button>



     <?php 

     }else{
    ?>
    <p>The status is inactive <?php echo $row['Status']; ?> </p>


    <?php

    }    



      ?>
    '</td>';
```

Considerign your `$row['Status']"` have the status `active`

Hope this suggestion helps you.